# Picking a variable in R

Tags: r

I have two variables: `X` and `state` which are given below

```
set.seed(3)
state <- rbinom(15,4,0.6)
X <- c(1:15)
X
state
```

and the output is

```
> state
 [1] 3 2 3 3 2 2 4 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
> X
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

I want to select the `X`s corresponding to the same state. Any idea how to do this in R?

Comment: Do you want to select X[3], X[2], X[3], X[3] etc?

Comment: No, not really, but you have given me a brilliant idea. X[state==2] works for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `split` you get a list of 4 states

```
ll <- split(X,state)
$`1`
[1] 15

$`2`
[1]  2  5  6  9 10 11 12 13 14

$`3`
[1] 1 3 4 8

$`4`
[1] 7

ll[3]
$`3`
[1] 1 3 4 8
```

generally we use , `ave` to perform some operations while grouping.

For example here I get the mean of X by state:

```
ave(X,state,FUN = mean)
 [1]  4.000000  9.111111  4.000000  4.000000  9.111111  9.111111  7.000000  4.000000  9.111111  9.111111  9.111111  9.111111  9.111111  9.111111 15.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to put you variables in a data frame and then select them from there:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = X, state = state)
> df
    x state
1   1     3
2   2     2
3   3     3
4   4     3
5   5     2
6   6     2
7   7     4
8   8     3
9   9     2
10 10     2
11 11     2
12 12     2
13 13     2
14 14     2
15 15     1
> df[df$state == 3,]
  x state
1 1     3
3 3     3
4 4     3
8 8     3
```

Comment: Putting the data in a data.frame certainly is not a bad idea. Your actual solution, however, is rather horrible. For once, the syntax using the for-loop is much more complicated the necessary (better use `tapply`), furthermore, print discards the structure and disallows further computation.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Thilo, i'll remove that part of the code.